# Finding the inverse of $x^2-x-2 \in \Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3-2x^2+2)$

Tags: polynomial-rings

I'm a relatively new student to this topic, please give comprehensive explanations

This is what I have so far:

We can use Euclidean algorithm to solve the following and we have:
$$\gcd(x^3-2x^2+2, x^2-x-2)=\gcd(x^3-2x^2+2-(x^2-x-2)(x-1),x^2-x-2)=\gcd(x, x^2-x-2)$$

And then:

$$\gcd(x, x^2-x-2-(x)(x-1))=\gcd(x,2)$$

Finally, I have,

$$2=g(x)-(x-1)(f(x)-(x-1)g(x))$$

So

$$1=g(x)(1+3x^2-x)+f(x)(3-3x)$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed, or might have made a mistake somewhere.

Please help and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not. This is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, written as a continued fraction rather than using back substitution. As usual, this requires fractions.   The piece of luck is that there is no factor of $5$  denominator. This means that you can just replace any factor $\frac{1}{2}$ by the factor $3.$  at the end. Note also that you could follow this exact method  but get rid of the fractions earlier, in the line $  \left(   x  \right)  =  \left( -2  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left(   x  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right)  =  \left(   x  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( -2  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x  \right)  =  \left( -2  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  - 2 x  + 2 \right) }{ \left(   x  - 1 \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{3}  + 2 x^{2}  - 2 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  +  x  + 2 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  - 2 x  + 2 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$